# Escalar ejes con ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Cuando hago un gráfico con `ggplot2` , ¿cómo se escala el eje de las y?
En mi caso cuando lo intento me da el siguiente error:

> Error in UseMethod("limits") :    no applicable method for 'limits'
>   applied to an object of class "list"

El código de R que uso es el siguiente:

```
ggplot(data=z, aes_string(x='date',y='AUC', group = 'ID', colour = 'c2'))+
  geom_line(alpha=0.45)+ ylim(min, max)
```

La variable AUC tiene valores entre 0 y 1.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Muchas gracias,

Marta

Comment: Parece que el error es que no tienes inicializados los valores de `min` y `max`, y te da ese error por que R esta asuminendo que estas pasando las funciones con esos nombres

Comment: Prueba usar `ylim(0,1)`